# Area between a semicircle and a 45° line

Tags: integration, area

I'm studying for a Calculus test and I met the following question:
There's a semicircle $$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ and a line at 45° degrees v=x. The task was to find the area in the positive quadrant.

I thought it would suffice to find the area between the extremes of the semicircle (in this case 0 and 1) and divide it by two (as I thought that a line at 45° would cut it in half) - Why is that not possible?

Also, in the solution I have they did the integral of $$\int^{\sqrt{1/2}}_1\sqrt{1-x^2}-x.dx$$ and not the integral of the function of the semicircle. Why? Does it has to do with the line? Would it be the area under the semicircle minus the area under the line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The extremes of the quarter-circle, you mean? ("in this case 0 and 1")

Your method works just fine, and in fact the integral form and your geometric short-cut are equivalent!

Answer (score 1):

[image: semi circle and id]

The green area in the image above is
$$
A
= \int\limits_0^z y(x) \, dx - \int\limits_0^z x \, dx 
= \int\limits_0^z \left( y(x) - x \right) \, dx
= \int\limits_0^z \left( \sqrt{1-x^2} - x \right) \, dx
$$
where $z$ is the $x$-coordinate of the point where $y$ and $\mbox{id}$ intersect. For this we have
$$
1 = z^2 + z^2 = 2 z^2 \Rightarrow z = 1/\sqrt{2}
$$
The integral from your solution seems to be the area $A_s$ in the image above, which looks a bit like a Star Trek logo triangle.

Comment: I actually didn't understand your answer. The area I'm looking for is the brown area plus As minus the outside area. In my simple thoughts it was the same as the green area...

Comment: Well going from the title *"Area between a semicircle and a 45° line"* and the information *"to find the area in the positive quadrant"* I must conclude that this means the green $A$ plus the Star Trek logo $A_s$. There is no more semi-circle in the positive quadrant.

Comment: The brown ares is the area between $\mbox{id}$ and the $x$-axis.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Your answer gets to the point, it just seems that I wrote the title wrong, but correctly by the same time. Thanks again. Btw, didn't know how was the StarTrek logo =//

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first sketch the situation and then split the integral into the problem of finding the area under the triangle with vertices at the origin, the intersection of your line with the semicircle and the point on the $x$-axis directly below it and the part of the semicircle from that $x$-value onwards.

Alternatively, you could realise that this is the problem of finding the area of $\frac18$ of a circle of radius 1 so the answer is $\frac\pi8$.

Comment: I liked your "Alternatively" - it seems to be in this case a smart way to check if the calculations went correctly.